# Relative positioning of UITextView and UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard, uitextview

I have a UITextView with static text and UIView with other content  underneath it and a margin between them in storyboard is about 10px.

When orientation changes the they both resize themselves horizontally, however the margin  gets much wider because UIView doesn't shift up.

I tried different autoresize settings, but can't get them to position correctly. This might be the noob question, but is there a way to make them behave like 'divs' in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but you can make a method which sets frame of label and view and call it from willAutorotate. You have to find the required frames for portrait as well as landscape and on rotation call the method. Also, call the same method from ViewDidLoad for initial setup of label & view. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Kenpachi! I was hoping I could avoid creating different layouts for different orientations, but looks like it's the way to go.